# Как настроить поддержку Stylus в React.js-приложении?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, stylus, create-react-app

Я хочу, чтобы классы в моём React.js-приложении были доступны для экспортирования из `.styl`-файлов таким же образом, как это можно сделать из CSS Modules, но я не могу найти никакого готового решения этой проблемы.

Я нашёл [инструкцию по настройке CSS Modules](https://habr.com/post/335244/) в приложении, созданном с помощью Create React App. Я понимаю, что нужно выполнить `npm run eject` и каким-то образом переписать конфигурационные файлы, но каким именно образом – не понимаю.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111496/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установить три npm-пакета в свой проект:

- [stylus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylus)
- [stylus-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylus-loader)
- [css-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader)

В конфигурационном файле вебпака, в разделе `module` добавить следующие пункты:

```
{
  test: /\.styl$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader?modules&camelCase&localIdentName=[path]__[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
    'stylus-loader',
  ],
},
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader',
  ],
},
```

Затем просто импортируем стили в реакт компоненты, вот так:

```
import style from './СomponentStyle.styl';
```

и используем в коде через имена вот так к примеру:

```
className={style.container}
```

где `container` - имя класса из CSS только без точки, а для вот такого имени к примеру: `.container-btn-green` нужно будет написать так: `style.containerBtnGreen` ну или так `style['container-btn-green']`